# How to transform this Prolog program into Lisp?

Tags: prolog, lisp, common-lisp

I'm trying to learn Common Lisp, and I want to know how to make a parser similar to the Prolog for as-monomial and do not know where to start.

```
as_monomial(X, m(X, 0, [])) :- number(X), !.  
as_monomial(^(Y, Z), m(1, Z, [v(Z, Y)])) :- !.  
as_monomial(^(X, 0), m(1, 0, [])) :-  !.  
as_monomial(*(X, ^(Y, Z)), m(G, K, Q)) :- 
  as_monomial(X, m(G, TD, Vars)), 
  K   is (TD + Z), 
  ordinamonomio([v(Z, Y)| Vars], Q),
  !.
as_monomial(*(X, Y), m(G, K, Q)) :- 
  as_monomial(X, m(G, TD, Vars)), 
  K is (TD + 1), 
  ordinamonomio([v(1, Y)| Vars], Q),
  !.
as_monomial(-(X), m(Q, Y, L)) :- 
  as_monomial(X, m(A, Y, L)), 
  Q is A *(-1), 
  !.
as_monomial(X, m(1, 1, [v(1, X)])).
```

Comment: Of interest: [Lisprolog - Interpreter for a simple Lisp, written in Prolog](https://www.metalevel.at/lisprolog/) and the [Prolog code](https://www.metalevel.at/lisprolog/lisprolog.pl)

Comment: I can't decide if my answer is really an answer to your specific question. It is more of an answer to the title question, `How to transform this Prolog program into Lisp?` than the specific question. I deleted then undeleted. I know the answer is in the ball park of what you seek but more of a theory type answer than a specific answer. If you don't consider it an answer, let me know and I will delete it. :)

Comment: Duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41246053/project-for-the-college

Comment: @RainerJoswig The destination of the link results in `page not found`. It can be found with a  [search](http://stackoverflow.com/search?q=project-for-the-college), but clicking on the link results in the error.

Comment: @GuyCoder: because the question showed not effort to solve the problem, just like this question here.

Comment: As you are new to StackOverflow, please take the [tour] and read [ask].

Comment: Let me start by asking: in what way is this a parser? What input does it take, and what should it produce?

Answer (score 3):

In your Prolog code, you rely mostly on pattern matching and recursion, but not backtracking, so you can easily translate it into Common Lisp without a major rework. I can show you a skeleton based on [generic functions](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/object-reorientation-generic-functions.html). I heavily recommend you to read the [Practical Common Lisp](http://www.gigamonkeys.com/book/) book if you are new to Common Lisp.

[`DEFGENERIC`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_defgen.htm) declares a function to be generic, i.e. one that dynamically dispatches according to the type or value of one or more arguments.

```
(defgeneric as-monomial (term)
  (:documentation "Express a term as a monomial."))
```

[`DEFMETHOD`](http://www.lispworks.com/documentation/lw50/CLHS/Body/m_defmet.htm) **specializes** the generic function based on the type or value of  its arguments. For example, you can have a specific implementation for numbers:

```
(defmethod as-monomial ((term number))
  `(m ,term 0 ()))
```

... and another one for `cons` cells, i.e. compound terms:

```
(defmethod as-monomial ((term cons))
  (destructuring-bind (operator left &optional right) term
    (case operator
      (^ ...)
      (* ...)
      (- ...))
```

See [`DESTRUCTURING-BIND`](http://clhs.lisp.se/Body/m_destru.htm). 
You can also have a default behavior:

```
;; fallback case
(defmethod as-monomial (term)
  `(m 1 1 ((v 1 ,term))))
```

Of course, you could define a single function which uses only `case` or `destructure-bind`, but generic methods scale better. For complex pattern matching needs (which is not the case here, IMO), you can use a pattern-matching library like [trivia](https://github.com/guicho271828/trivia).

Comment: No Thanks needed, but appreciated. It is not about the points but about helping other people learn as a community. I consider the upvote a sign saying this is the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

Reference: [Lisprolog - Interpreter for a simple Lisp, written in Prolog](https://www.metalevel.at/lisprolog/)

This uses [Prolog DCG](https://www.metalevel.at/prolog/dcg) for which I find books such as "[Prolog Programming for Artificial Intelligence](http://www.worldcat.org/oclc/13095396)" by Ivan Bratko to be better for learning DCGs.

```erlang
/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
    Lisprolog -- Interpreter for a simple Lisp. Written in Prolog.
    Written Nov. 26th, 2006 by Markus Triska (triska@metalevel.at).
    Public domain code.
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

:- set_prolog_flag(double_quotes, chars).

/* - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - -
   Parsing
- - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - - */

parsing(String, Exprs) :- phrase(expressions(Exprs), String).

expressions([E|Es]) -->
    ws, expression(E), ws,
    !, % single solution: longest input match
    expressions(Es).
expressions([]) --> [].

ws --> [W], { char_type(W, space) }, ws.
ws --> [].

% A number N is represented as n(N), a symbol S as s(S).

expression(s(A))         --> symbol(Cs), { atom_chars(A, Cs) }.
expression(n(N))         --> number(Cs), { number_chars(N, Cs) }.
expression(List)         --> "(", expressions(List), ")".
expression([s(quote),Q]) --> "'", expression(Q).

number([D|Ds]) --> digit(D), number(Ds).
number([D])    --> digit(D).

digit(D) --> [D], { char_type(D, digit) }.

symbol([A|As]) -->
    [A],
    { memberchk(A, "+/-*><=") ; char_type(A, alpha) },
    symbolr(As).

symbolr([A|As]) -->
    [A],
    { memberchk(A, "+/-*><=") ; char_type(A, alnum) },
    symbolr(As).
symbolr([]) --> [].
```

### TL;DR

The reference is part of [Markus Triska's website](https://www.metalevel.at/) which contains many other useful Prolog resources. He is also active on [GitHub](https://github.com/triska)

Comment: While interesting,  the snippet is about parsing Lisp expressions as Prolog term. Doing the opposite would be closer to what OP wants to do, IMO.

Comment: @coredump I totally agree. It was after reading your answer then re-reading the question that made me delete my answer. But then after reading again and seeing the upvotes on the comment and answer I decided to leave it to the OP to decide. I also agree with the close vote about the question being unclear. I always find it interesting how new people can toss monkey wrenches into this. After many years here I just help the new people as best as I can as I remember how frustrating it was for me to move from forums to this Q&A format.